# What is the proper way to allow ipv6 (both single address and network) in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ipv6

See below what I tried so far for ipV6. It doesn't work. The part concerning ipV4 works fine.

```
     <Files *.php>
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from all
     allow from 170.158
     allow from 2604:2000:69d4:a600:a894:449b:8749:7f4d
     allow from 2604:2000:69d4:a600:0041:0e76:4563:5aaa
     </Files>
```

Comment: One thing to think about with the IPv6 addresses is that they appear to be randomly generated privacy addresses (most OSes do that now), and they are subject to change from time to time.

Comment: hence the idea of allowing the network. not just one address. but not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I got: IT does work with both, IPv4 and IPv6, a question would be how to allow IPv6 with a range.

```
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html

RedirectMatch 403 ^/folder/.*$

SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "2804:388:d042:e9e7:c5f2:6aba:1ed2:38df" realremoteaddr
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "2804:214:82c6:b526:71eb:85b2:5111:88de" realremoteaddr
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "2804:214:82c6:b526:8c98:8e23:54ec:bd48" realremoteaddr
allow from env=realremoteaddr

#deny from 187.84.4.102
```